# How do I get GPS coordinates from iPhone / Android?

Tags: php, geolocation

I need to get the coordinates of users visiting my site, so I can figure out what country / city / street they are at.

Currently I'm doing this by using the IP address. But mobile devises don't have that (I think).

I googled a bit and looked at Stackoverflow, but have not found how this can be done using PHP - only javascript.

Can this only be achieved by using javascript? If yes, do I need a library?

Comment: what do you mean by "mobile devices don't have that" (an ip) ? how can a device have internet access without an ip address? how are you checking the ip address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML5 you have (JavaScript) access to the Geolocation API. More can be found on [*Dive Into HTML5*](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/geolocation.html).

In short, yes, JavaScript is the way to go if the location should be found client-side (i.e., on the device). You should, however, be able to continue the server-based (IP-based) look-up as before, since mobile devices are just another client sending requests to your server.

Comment: I'm guessing the IP address being used is from my phone operator. Do you know if this IP Address will change from one city to another?

Comment: @Steven I suspect this to depend on the operator (and, perhaps, whether the phone is roaming).

Answer (score 1):

There's a Javascript library for that:

http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/